# Spring batch trigger process after all jobs complete

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application with a series of jobs.  I want to send an email after ALL the jobs have completed, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.  The options I am considering are:

1. Run the jobs in a certain order, and amend the JobListener of the last job, so that it will send the email.  Downside with this is it won't work if a further job is added to the end of the batch.
2. Add a new job which will send the email and order the jobs, making sure this additional job is run last.
3. Are there any built in spring-batch constructs that will be triggered on completion of the entire batch?

The final option would be my preferred solution, so my question is, are there any spring-batch classes that listen for batch completion (similar to JobExecutionListenerSupport or a Step Listener)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a job of jobs. In this case, you can define an enclosing job with a series of steps of type `JobStep` (which delegates to a job). Then, you can register a `JobExecutionListener` on the enclosing job. This listener will be called once all steps (ie sub-jobs) have completed.

More details about the `JobStep` here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html

Comment: The job execution listener's afterJob method is called before the jobRepository.update(execution) method is called. Is there a way to configure some listener after the update is called in other words how do we know that the job has completely finished and we can get its data from the database?

Comment: @humbleCoder No, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/b7d144c10d43e18b06f7921d751f97e21ab4a9a7/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/AbstractJob.java#L372-L381. If you want to do something after the job repository update, you really need to write code after `JobLauncher.run(yourJob, yourJobParameters)` returns.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If the job runs in a different thread though this won't work right?

Comment: @humbleCoder If the job is executed in a different thread, you need to get a handle to the `JobExecution` returned by `JobLauncher.run(yourJob, yourJobParameters)` and check its status until it is completed.

Comment: Mahmoud Ben Hassine : Can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768221/getlastjobexecution-in-jdbcjobexecutiondao-of-spring-batch-returns-incorrect-las

Answer (score 1):

No. I am not aware of any batch listener that listen for the whole batch's completion.

I have two alternatives for you. Both allows you to stick to Spring.

(1) If your application is designed as perpetual (i.e. like a web-server), you can inject a custom `jobLauncher`, grab the `TaskExecutor` and wait its completion (either through simple counters that counts call-backs from afterJob functions or through a certain amount of time that it requires all jobs to be submitted -- not necessarily started).

Add a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
class JobConfiguration implements InitializingBean {
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Bean TaskExecutor taskExecutor () {
        // here, change to your liking, in this example
        // I put a SyncTaskExecutor
        taskExecutor = new SyncTaskExecutor();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean 
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(@Autowired JobRepository jobRepository,
        @Autowired TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        launcher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        return launcher;
    }

    List<Job> jobs; 

    // I don't use this in this example
    // however, jobs.size() will help you with the countdown latch
    @Autowired public void setJobs (List<Job> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @AfterPropertiesSet
    public void init () {
        // either countdown until all jobs are submitted 
        // or sleep a finite amount of time
        // in this example, I'll be lazy and just sleep
        Thread.sleep(1 * 3600 * 1000L); // wait 1 hour
        taskExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
            taskExecutor.awaitTermination();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        finally {
            // send your e-mail here. 
        }
    }
}
```

(2) If your application stops when all jobs are done, you can simply follow [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown) to send out an e-mail.

I repeat a few lines of code for completeness:

```
public class TerminateBean {

    @PreDestroy
    public void onDestroy() throws Exception {
        // send out e-mail here
    }
}
```

We also have to add a bean of this type:

```
@Configuration
public class ShutdownConfig {

    @Bean
    public TerminateBean getTerminateBean() {
        return new TerminateBean();
    }
}
```